# Connecting to socket.io successful but terminal not showing any log

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have an app.js placed in my html.

Here is its basic code

```
var EVENT_CONNECTED = "cityConnected";

var mysql = require('mysql');
var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host :'localhost',
    user : 'root',
    password:'a!aba',
    database :'asdfsdf'
});
con.connect();

var server  = require('http').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
console.log("Connecting");
console.log("Connecting");
io.on('connection',function(socket)
{
   console.log("Connecting");
....
```

I am using mac terminal at html> i am doing `pm2 start app`. I can see the process being started. However i am unable to get any log when console code is there. How can i see log in `terminal`?

Comment: Are you loading your app's home page in a browser? Can you post the browser-side socket.io-client code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pm2 logs app` to see all logs of app.js.

Comment: ah great it works, is there any way to continue logging in terminal as soon as new log is generated?

Comment: When you will run `pm2 logs app` you see logs of 'app.js' process in real-time. To stop the streaming of logs use hotkey Ctrl + Z. If you want to kill process 'app.js' use `pm2 delete app`. Read more about log managment in pm2 [here](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/log-management/)